# How to make trigger script in paired image button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking for a way to deactivate/trigger a single or multiple button in a paired image button.

Currently, the default display will be:
Predator Only - Lion - Wolf - Tiger - Shark - Cheetah

In this condition, I want that:

If I click the lion or wolf or tiger or shark or cheetah and change it to its pair,
The first image, "predator only", will be changed to mixed.

If I click "Predator only" and change it to "mixed",
All - Lion - Wolf - Tiger - Shark - Cheetah will change to its pair

If I click "Mixed" and change it to "Predator Only"
All - Deer - Lamb - Goat - Seal - Gazelle will change to its pair

If I keep changing and the following: Lion - Wolf - Tiger - Shark - Cheetah is being displayed once again
It will trigger to make the first image button display "Predator only".

Please show me how to do this...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).siblings());
    $(this).add($(this).siblings()).toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
/* For layout only */
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Used to hide image */
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/3tsfw9psl/Predator.png" />
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/nn4joz36d/Mixed.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ski4a355h/Lion.png" />
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/s2myu8fkl/Deer.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/vxvetx51x/Wolf.png" />
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ty9r5e4et/Lamb.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ll42aq579/Tiger.png" />
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/f11a4dr6d/Goat.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/flgb72ket/Shark.png" />
  <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/rk8v1dv9p/Seal.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/wn9595z9x/Cheetah.png" />
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/h4bpc1qz9/Gazelle.png" class="hide" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around classes to know what is hidden. If a predator is hidden, then it is mixed, otherwise it is predator only.

When you click on the "predator only" and "mixed" button, you should also be able to know which one you want to toggle.

The following code should work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).siblings()).toggleClass('hide');
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'predator_only') {
      $('.predator:not(.hide)').add($('.predator:not(.hide)').siblings()).toggleClass('hide');
    }
    else if($(this).attr('id') == 'mixed') {
      $('.predator.hide').add($('.predator.hide').siblings()).toggleClass('hide');
    }
    else
    {
      if($('.predator.hide').length > 0) {
        $('#mixed').removeClass('hide');
        $('#predator_only').addClass('hide');
      }
      else {
        $('#mixed').addClass('hide');
        $('#predator_only').removeClass('hide');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* For layout only */
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Used to hide image */
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/3tsfw9psl/Predator.png" id="predator_only"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/nn4joz36d/Mixed.png" class="hide" id="mixed"/>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ski4a355h/Lion.png" class="predator" />
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/s2myu8fkl/Deer.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/vxvetx51x/Wolf.png" class="predator"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ty9r5e4et/Lamb.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ll42aq579/Tiger.png" class="predator"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/f11a4dr6d/Goat.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/flgb72ket/Shark.png" class="predator"/>
  <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/rk8v1dv9p/Seal.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/wn9595z9x/Cheetah.png" class="predator"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/h4bpc1qz9/Gazelle.png" class="hide" />
</div>
</div>
```